# Magento checkout add custom calculation in backend

Tags: checkout, customer

i want to override checkout flow and add custom field in table based on user who checkout :

suppose customer with id 10 completed checkout , i want to do entry in table with customer id and same custom value .

where have i to write code ??.. which magento event should i override in my custom module

Answer (score 1):

You can use `checkout_submit_all_after`.
It is dispatched when the quote is transformed to an order and your receive as parameters the quote, the order and the recurring profiles (if any).